# Nginx server not running with Gatsbyjs default Docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gatsby

I have a working `gatsbyjs` project that doesn't run from the official Docker image.

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gatsbyjs/gatsby:latest
ADD public/ /pub
```

(the compiled website is at `public/` and I've confirmed the `index.html` renders the website correctly)

I also tried the official `Dockerfile`, which didn't work:

```
FROM gatsbyjs/gatsby:onbuild
```

I'm running this from `docker-compose` as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:
  website:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Nginx returns a "500 Internal Server Error".

I'm following the official tutorial [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-docker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `onbuild` image isn't rebuilt when the `latest` image is updated, which causes docker to pull an outdated version of the base image.
You can better ignore the `onbuild` image and take the latest.
[Here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world) you can find the details.

To test if the latest image works.

First I tried to run a container from the image:

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 gatsbyjs/gatsby:latest
```

This works. Nginx is running here.

```
$ curl localhost
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
```

Delete the container.

I'll install gatsby globally

```
$ npm install --global gatsby-cli
```

Now I cloned a basic gatsbyjs site from [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git
$ cd gatsby-starter-hello-world\
```

I'll build the site (as desribed in your doc).
    $ npm install
    $ gatsby build

Now I've a `public/` repository. This is what the image with the `:onbuild` tag expects.

```
LICENSE  README.md  node_modules/  package-lock.json  package.json  public/  src/
```

Now I can write my Dockerfile in the git repo. i'll use the latest tag (not onbuild) which means I have to write my own `COPY` or `ADD` step. It contains:

```
FROM gatsbyjs/gatsby:latest
COPY public/ /pub
```

I'll build the docker image

```
$ docker build -t my-site .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.791MB
Step 1/2 : FROM gatsbyjs/gatsby:latest
 ---> 21fc487ad83e
Step 2/2 : COPY public/ /pub
 ---> 87f5ea1018ee
Removing intermediate container fd35cace6ef0
Successfully built 87f5ea1018ee
Successfully tagged my-site:latest
```

And finally I can start a docker container from the image.

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 my-site
```

Now I can `curl` my `localhost:80`

```
$ curl localhost
$<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/><link rel="preload" href="/component---src-pages-index-js-3a9c8c6504e39c44af75.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/path---index-a0e39f21c11f6a62c5ab.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/app-fcd7d98e3197e34ce021.js" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/commons-eef92a68af65d2662677.js" as="script"/><style id="gatsby-inlined-css"></style></head><body><div id="___gatsby"><div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="-122217258"><div data-reactid="2">Hello world!</div></div></div><script id="webpack-manifest">/*<![CDATA[*/window.webpackManifest={"231608221292675":"app-fcd7d98e3197e34ce021.js","35783957827783":"component---src-pages-index-js-3a9c8c6504e39c44af75.js","142629428675168":"path---index-a0e39f21c11f6a62c5ab.js"}/*]]>*/</script><script>/*<![CDATA[*/!function(e,t,r){function n(){for(;d[0]&&"loaded"==d[0][f];)c=d.shift(),c[o]=!i.parentNode.insertBefore(c,i)}for(var..
```

Comment: Hi @lvthillo, really appreciate the detailed answer. Unfortunately, as you can see, I have tried this approach and I'm still getting the 404 even with `./public`.

Comment: I have tried this approach with the docker image and the fault is definitely in the `docker-compose` setup. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Well I tried with your docker-compose file and it works. Be sure the Dockerfile is right. My dockerfile is the same as above and I started docker-compose with: docker-compose up -d --build

Comment: Rookie mistake - forgot to re-build before docker-compose up!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!